# How to output list of HTML links from an array using Pug?

Tags: pug

I have a JavaScript array `tweetStreams`:

```
var tweetStreams = ["ScalaCourses", "Promotion1", "Promotion2"];
```

I want to have Pug (current version) output a list of links, rendered to HTML that looks like:

```
<a href='#ScalaCourses'>ScalaCourses</a> <a href='#Promotion1'>Promotion1</a> <a href='#Promotion2'>Promotion2</a>
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
for ts in tweetStreams
    a(href= ts) #{ts}&nbsp;
```

Output is:

`<a href="ScalaCourses">ScalaCourses&nbsp;</a><a href="Promotion1">Promotion1&nbsp;</a><a href="Promotion2">Promotion2&nbsp;</a>`

1. How to prefix the link with `#` so it is a local link?
2. Is there a way to avoid using `&nbsp;`?
3. I want a space between the links, not within them

### Update

Modifying @gandreadis answer, I have:

```
a(href= "#" + ts) #{ts}
    | &nbsp;
```

Visually this gives a good result, and this solution solves questions 1 and 3. Using a quoted space instead of `&nbsp;` yields quote marks in the output, unfortunately. Is there any way to address question 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer to Q1:* By prefixing the link with `#`: `a(href= "#" + ts)`

*Answer to Q3:* CSS is probably the cleanest way to go for margins, but if you insist on using Pug for this, see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/GyWVby). Basically, adding a trailing `| #{' '}`-line should do the job of separating the inline elements:

```
for ts in tweetStreams
    a(href= "#" + ts) #{ts}
    | #{' '}
```

(note that this also eliminates the need for that non-breaking space you asked about in *Q2*)

Comment: When I combine your two answers there is no space between the words unless I add a trailing space to the 2nd line. I don't like that, because the space is not noticeable, and editors often remove trailing whitespace when files are saved. What other options are there?

Comment: Well, that depends on what your definition of 'space' is. If you're referring to a space margin (as in, a certain amount of pixels between the elements), then my solution should work for you (see my CodePen example, which does has 'space' between the words). If you're looking for the space character, that's a different story (let me know which version you're looking for)

Comment: I mean a space character. When I paste your code example into my project the only way the links are not concatenated together is if I add (invisible) whitespace at the end of `a(href= ts) #{ts}`

Comment: I think I've found a way, see the updated code in my answer

Comment: Those quote marks show up in the rendered output, unfortunately

Comment: I can't reproduce that, unfortunately, see the CodePen. No quotation marks there, and if I inspect the raw HTML output, I get this: `<a href="#ScalaCourses">ScalaCourses</a> <a href="#Promotion1">Promotion1</a> <a href="#Promotion2">Promotion2</a>` (which should the thing you're looking for, right?)

Comment: Yes, that is the desired HTML output. I do not know why the codepen shows a different result. Possibly because of a setting or command-line option when running the webapp, or some dependency that I have or do not have? I just type `npm start`.

Comment: Does not seem like an issue that would come from a missing argument or dependency. One last attempt: Have you tried `| #{' '}` instead of `= ' '`?

Comment: YES! That works. If you update your answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works! I've updated my answer accordingly.